# Getting elements in an adjacency list

Tags: c++, list, vector, adjacency-list

I have a question regarding adjacency lists. This is an example list I am using.

[image]

In code (C++), I am implementing this as a vector of lists of some generic element. So `vector<list< element >>`. In this case, the elements `A, C, D, H, K, L, N` are all in a vector. My question is grabbing a particular element. Say I use a for loop to iterate through the vector `adjList`. To get an element from a vector, you'd say `*vector name*[i]` and that gets the element by itself. But what does it do when the element in the vector is the beginning of a list? Let's say I only want element `D`. To get that I say `adjList[3]`. Would that grab just `D`? Or would saying that grab the whole list that starts at `D`? I don't want the whole list, I just want `D`. If it grabs the whole list, how would I get it to grab just the one element I want? Can someone help explain?

Comment: Is this a `std::vector` and a `std::list`?

Comment: Yes, they are the std vector and list.

Answer (score 1):

As you write yourself, you have a `vector<list< element >>`. That means that `adjList[i]` will give you a **list**. Your A,C,D elements are accessed as `adjList[i].front()`, or verbosely,

```cpp
list< element > l = adjList[i];
element D = l.front();
```

The latter may be useful if you'll need to work with the rest of the list too.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I wasn't sure if it would give me a list or not but now I understand. Thank you for clearing that up for me.